# How can i make the sum and show it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why isn't the third command working?
It is supposed to make the sum of the prices and show in the website page.

```
liga.Open();
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
comando.CommandText = "select count (*) from M16_Tbl_Cart where ID_User=" + Session["IDuser"] + "";
comando.Connection = liga;
int numProd = (int)comando.ExecuteScalar();
comando.CommandText = "SELECT Image, Name, Size, Price FROM dbo.M16_Tbl_Cart where ID_User="+Session["IDuser"]+"";
comando.Connection = liga;
comando.CommandText = "SELECT sum(Price) as PriceSum from M16_Tbl_Cart where ID_User=" + Session["IDuser"] + "";
comando.Connection = liga;
SqlDataReader dataReader = comando.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: There's not enough context here, but you're not executing the second statement and not showing what you do with the results of the third.

Comment: while (dataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
               
                       Name = (dataReader["Name"]).ToString();
                       Price = (dataReader["Price"]).ToString();
                       Size = (dataReader["Size"]).ToString();
                       Image = (dataReader["Image"]).ToString();
                       ProdSum = (dataReader["ProdSum"]).ToString();

                    }
                    dataReader.NextResult();
                }
                liga.Close();

Comment: it does that. and after the result should appear in the website. but it is not showing the ProdSum value.